# Force to show min/max on x axis

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I am working with [library](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts). Anybody know if is it possible to force show min and max label on x-axis.

What I have:

[image]

What I want to achieve:

[image]

My implementation:

```
private func prepareXAxis() {
    lineChart.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    lineChart.xAxis.valueFormatter = ChartXAxisDateValueFormatter()
    lineChart.xAxis.labelFont = UIFont.pmd_robotoRegular(ofSize: 13.0)
    lineChart.xAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.pmd_darkGrey
}
```

And implementation of my own `ValueFormatter`:

```
import Foundation
import Charts

class ChartXAxisDateValueFormatter: NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter {

    func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm\ndd MMM"

        return dateFormatter.string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: value))
    }
}
```

#### Edit

I added this code but first and last label on x-axis is still skipped:

```
lineChart.xAxis.axisMinimum = lineDataSet.xMin
lineChart.xAxis.axisMaximum = lineDataSet.xMax
lineChart.xAxis.avoidFirstLastClippingEnabled = false
lineChart.xAxis.granularity = 1.0
```

I checked `lineDataSet.xMin` and `lineDataSet.xMax`. They have valid values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. The lost line:

`combinedChart.xAxis.forceLabelsEnabled = true`

I also changed type of chart from `LineChart` to `CombinedChartView`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set below property for not skip 1st and last value

```
//Set up XAxis into chart.
lineChart.xAxis.axisMinimum = 0
lineChart.xAxis.avoidFirstLastClippingEnabled = NO
lineChart.xAxis.granularity = 1.0
```

Hope this will helps.

Comment: Please look on my `ChartXAxisDateValueFormatter` my x values are timestamps. When I set `lineChart.xAxis.axisMinimum = 0` the xAxis look like this: https://ibb.co/fPj4i5 I tried set `lineChart.xAxis,axisMinimum = lineDataSet.xMin` but it didn't work. First value is still skipped.